# SwiftChart Add Range Highlighting

Tags: swift, swiftcharts

I'm using the [Swift Chart](https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart). I'd like to modify it to allow the user to select a range. The idea is to touch, swipe left/right, and then lift your finger. This should highlight the area swiped and provide a way to get the beginning and ending values of the swipe. I expect I'll need to modify the `touchesBegan()` and `touchesEnded()` events, but I don't know how.

Comment: Show Tried Code, Expected Output and which Swift Chart Module You are using now ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make this work:

I added range selection variables to the class

```
// Range selection
open var leftRangePoint: UITouch!
open var rightRangePoint: UITouch!
open var leftRangeLocation: CGFloat = 0
open var rightRangeLocation: CGFloat = 0
```

I modified touchesBegan()

```
leftRangePoint = touches.first!
leftRangeLocation = leftRangePoint.location(in: self).x
```

And added a routine to touchesEnded()

```
handleRangeTouchesEnded(touches, event: event)
```

Here's the full code:

```
//  Chart.swift
//
//  Created by Giampaolo Bellavite on 07/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Giampaolo Bellavite. All rights reserved.
import UIKit

public protocol ChartDelegate: class {
    func didTouchChart(_ chart: Chart, indexes: [Int?], x: Float, left: CGFloat)
    func didFinishTouchingChart(_ chart: Chart)
    func didEndTouchingChart(_ chart: Chart)
}

typealias ChartPoint = (x: Float, y: Float)
public enum ChartLabelOrientation {
    case horizontal
    case vertical
}

@IBDesignable open class Chart: UIControl {
    @IBInspectable
    open var identifier: String?
    open var series: [ChartSeries] = [] {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    open var xLabels: [Float]?
    open var xLabelsFormatter = { (labelIndex: Int, labelValue: Float) -> String in
        String(Int(labelValue))
    }

    open var xLabelsTextAlignment: NSTextAlignment = .left
    open var xLabelsOrientation: ChartLabelOrientation = .horizontal
    open var xLabelsSkipLast: Bool = true
    open var xLabelsSkipAll: Bool = true
    open var yLabels: [Float]?
    open var yLabelsFormatter = { (labelIndex: Int, labelValue: Float) -> String in
        String(Int(labelValue))
    }

    open var yLabelsOnRightSide: Bool = false
    open var labelFont: UIFont? = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    @IBInspectable
    open var labelColor: UIColor = UIColor.black

    @IBInspectable
    open var axesColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.3)

    @IBInspectable
    open var gridColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    open var showXLabelsAndGrid: Bool = true
    open var showYLabelsAndGrid: Bool = true
    open var bottomInset: CGFloat = 20
    open var topInset: CGFloat = 20

    @IBInspectable
    open var lineWidth: CGFloat = 2

    weak open var delegate: ChartDelegate?

    open var minX: Float?
    open var minY: Float?
    open var maxX: Float?
    open var maxY: Float?
    open var highlightLineColor = UIColor.gray
    open var highlightLineWidth: CGFloat = 0.5
    open var areaAlphaComponent: CGFloat = 0.1
    open var leftRangePoint: UITouch!
    open var rightRangePoint: UITouch!
    open var leftRangeLocation: CGFloat = 0
    open var rightRangeLocation: CGFloat = 0

    fileprivate var highlightShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    fileprivate var layerStore: [CAShapeLayer] = []

    fileprivate var drawingHeight: CGFloat!
    fileprivate var drawingWidth: CGFloat!

    fileprivate var min: ChartPoint!
    fileprivate var max: ChartPoint!

    typealias ChartLineSegment = [ChartPoint]

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    convenience public init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        contentMode = .redraw // redraw rects on bounds change
    }

    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
            drawIBPlaceholder()
            #else
            drawChart()
        #endif
    }

    open func add(_ series: ChartSeries) {
        self.series.append(series)
    }

    open func add(_ series: [ChartSeries]) {
        for s in series {
            add(s)
        }
    }

    open func removeSeriesAt(_ index: Int) {
        series.remove(at: index)
    }

    open func removeAllSeries() {
        series = []
    }

    open func valueForSeries(_ seriesIndex: Int, atIndex dataIndex: Int?) -> Float? {
        if dataIndex == nil { return nil }
        let series = self.series[seriesIndex] as ChartSeries
        return series.data[dataIndex!].y
    }

    fileprivate func drawIBPlaceholder() {
        let placeholder = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        placeholder.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.93, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1)
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Chart"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.frame.origin.x += frame.width/2 - (label.frame.width / 2)
        label.frame.origin.y += frame.height/2 - (label.frame.height / 2)

        placeholder.addSubview(label)
        addSubview(placeholder)
    }

    fileprivate func drawChart() {
        drawingHeight = bounds.height - bottomInset - topInset
        drawingWidth = bounds.width

        let minMax = getMinMax()
        min = minMax.min
        max = minMax.max

        highlightShapeLayer = nil

        // Remove things before drawing, e.g. when changing orientation
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        for layer in layerStore {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        layerStore.removeAll()

        // Draw content
        for (index, series) in self.series.enumerated() {
            // Separate each line in multiple segments over and below the x axis
            let segments = Chart.segmentLine(series.data as ChartLineSegment, zeroLevel: series.colors.zeroLevel)

            segments.forEach({ segment in
                let scaledXValues = scaleValuesOnXAxis( segment.map({ return $0.x }) )
                let scaledYValues = scaleValuesOnYAxis( segment.map({ return $0.y }) )

                if series.line {
                    drawLine(scaledXValues, yValues: scaledYValues, seriesIndex: index)
                }
                if series.area {
                    drawArea(scaledXValues, yValues: scaledYValues, seriesIndex: index)
                }
            })
        }

        drawAxes()

        if showXLabelsAndGrid && (xLabels != nil || series.count > 0) {
            drawLabelsAndGridOnXAxis()
        }
        if showYLabelsAndGrid && (yLabels != nil || series.count > 0) {
            drawLabelsAndGridOnYAxis()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func getMinMax() -> (min: ChartPoint, max: ChartPoint) {
        // Start with user-provided values
        var min = (x: minX, y: minY)
        var max = (x: maxX, y: maxY)

        // Check in datasets
        for series in self.series {
            let xValues =  series.data.map({ (point: ChartPoint) -> Float in
                return point.x })
           let yValues =  series.data.map({ (point: ChartPoint) -> Float in
                return point.y })

            let newMinX = xValues.min()!
            let newMinY = yValues.min()!
            let newMaxX = xValues.max()!
            let newMaxY = yValues.max()!

            if min.x == nil || newMinX < min.x! { min.x = newMinX }
            if min.y == nil || newMinY < min.y! { min.y = newMinY }
            if max.x == nil || newMaxX > max.x! { max.x = newMaxX }
            if max.y == nil || newMaxY > max.y! { max.y = newMaxY }
        }

        // Check in labels
        if xLabels != nil {
            let newMinX = (xLabels!).min()!
            let newMaxX = (xLabels!).max()!
            if min.x == nil || newMinX < min.x! { min.x = newMinX }
            if max.x == nil || newMaxX > max.x! { max.x = newMaxX }
        }

        if yLabels != nil {
            let newMinY = (yLabels!).min()!
            let newMaxY = (yLabels!).max()!
            if min.y == nil || newMinY < min.y! { min.y = newMinY }
            if max.y == nil || newMaxY > max.y! { max.y = newMaxY }
        }

        if min.x == nil { min.x = 0 }
        if min.y == nil { min.y = 0 }
        if max.x == nil { max.x = 0 }
        if max.y == nil { max.y = 0 }

        return (min: (x: min.x!, y: min.y!), max: (x: max.x!, max.y!))
    }

    fileprivate func scaleValuesOnXAxis(_ values: [Float]) -> [Float] {
        let width = Float(drawingWidth)

        var factor: Float
        if max.x - min.x == 0 {
            factor = 0
        } else {
            factor = width / (max.x - min.x)
        }

        let scaled = values.map { factor * ($0 - self.min.x) }
        return scaled
    }

    fileprivate func scaleValuesOnYAxis(_ values: [Float]) -> [Float] {
        let height = Float(drawingHeight)
        var factor: Float
        if max.y - min.y == 0 {
            factor = 0
        } else {
            factor = height / (max.y - min.y)
        }

        let scaled = values.map { Float(self.topInset) + height - factor * ($0 - self.min.y) }
        return scaled
    }

    fileprivate func scaleValueOnYAxis(_ value: Float) -> Float {
        let height = Float(drawingHeight)
        var factor: Float
        if max.y - min.y == 0 {
            factor = 0
        } else {
            factor = height / (max.y - min.y)
        }

        let scaled = Float(self.topInset) + height - factor * (value - min.y)
        return scaled
    }

    fileprivate func getZeroValueOnYAxis(zeroLevel: Float) -> Float {
        if min.y > zeroLevel {
            return scaleValueOnYAxis(min.y)
        } else {
            return scaleValueOnYAxis(zeroLevel)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func drawLine(_ xValues: [Float], yValues: [Float], seriesIndex: Int) {
        // YValues are "reverted" from top to bottom, so 'above' means <= level
        let isAboveZeroLine = yValues.max()! <= self.scaleValueOnYAxis(series[seriesIndex].colors.zeroLevel)
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xValues.first!), y: CGFloat(yValues.first!)))
        for i in 1..<yValues.count {
            let y = yValues[i]
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xValues[i]), y: CGFloat(y)))
        }

        let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        lineLayer.frame = self.bounds
        lineLayer.path = path

        if isAboveZeroLine {
            lineLayer.strokeColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.above.cgColor
        } else {
            lineLayer.strokeColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.below.cgColor
        }
        lineLayer.fillColor = nil
        lineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        lineLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel

        self.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)

        layerStore.append(lineLayer)
    }

    fileprivate func drawArea(_ xValues: [Float], yValues: [Float], seriesIndex: Int) {
        // YValues are "reverted" from top to bottom, so 'above' means <= level
        let isAboveZeroLine = yValues.max()! <= self.scaleValueOnYAxis(series[seriesIndex].colors.zeroLevel)
        let area = CGMutablePath()
        let zero = CGFloat(getZeroValueOnYAxis(zeroLevel: series[seriesIndex].colors.zeroLevel))

        area.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xValues[0]), y: zero))
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            area.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xValues[i]), y: CGFloat(yValues[i])))
        }
        area.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xValues.last!), y: zero))
        let areaLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        areaLayer.frame = self.bounds
        areaLayer.path = area
        areaLayer.strokeColor = nil
        if isAboveZeroLine {
            areaLayer.fillColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.above.withAlphaComponent(areaAlphaComponent).cgColor
        } else {
            areaLayer.fillColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.below.withAlphaComponent(areaAlphaComponent).cgColor
        }
        areaLayer.lineWidth = 0

        self.layer.addSublayer(areaLayer)

        layerStore.append(areaLayer)
    }

    fileprivate func drawAxes() {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setStrokeColor(axesColor.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(0.5)

        // horizontal axis at the bottom
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: drawingHeight + topInset))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(drawingWidth), y: drawingHeight + topInset))
        context.strokePath()

        // horizontal axis at the top
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0)))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(drawingWidth), y: CGFloat(0)))
        context.strokePath()

        // horizontal axis when y = 0
        if min.y < 0 && max.y > 0 {
            let y = CGFloat(getZeroValueOnYAxis(zeroLevel: 0))
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: y))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(drawingWidth), y: y))
            context.strokePath()
        }

        // vertical axis on the left
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0)))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: drawingHeight + topInset))
        context.strokePath()

        // vertical axis on the right
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(drawingWidth), y: CGFloat(0)))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(drawingWidth), y: drawingHeight + topInset))
        context.strokePath()
    }

    fileprivate func drawLabelsAndGridOnXAxis() {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setStrokeColor(gridColor.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(0.5)

        var labels: [Float]
        if xLabels == nil {
            // Use labels from the first series
            labels = series[0].data.map({ (point: ChartPoint) -> Float in
                return point.x })
        } else {
            labels = xLabels!
        }

        let scaled = scaleValuesOnXAxis(labels)
        let padding: CGFloat = 5
        scaled.enumerated().forEach { (i, value) in
            let x = CGFloat(value)
            let isLastLabel = x == drawingWidth

            // Add vertical grid for each label, except axes on the left and right
            if x != 0 && x != drawingWidth {
                context.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: CGFloat(0)))

                if xLabelsSkipAll {
                    let height: CGFloat = bounds.height - 20.0
                    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: height))
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.height))
                }

                context.strokePath()
            }

            if (xLabelsSkipLast && isLastLabel) || xLabelsSkipAll {
                // Do not add label at the most right position
                return
            }

            // Add label
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: drawingHeight, width: 0, height: 0))
            label.font = labelFont
            label.text = xLabelsFormatter(i, labels[i])
            label.textColor = labelColor

            // Set label size
            label.sizeToFit()
            // Center label vertically
            label.frame.origin.y += topInset
            if xLabelsOrientation == .horizontal {
                // Add left padding
                label.frame.origin.y -= (label.frame.height - bottomInset) / 2
                label.frame.origin.x += padding

                // Set label's text alignment
                label.frame.size.width = (drawingWidth / CGFloat(labels.count)) - padding * 2
                label.textAlignment = xLabelsTextAlignment
            } else {
                label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))

                // Adjust vertical position according to the label's height
                label.frame.origin.y += label.frame.size.height / 2

                // Adjust horizontal position as the series line
                label.frame.origin.x = x
                if xLabelsTextAlignment == .center {
                    // Align horizontally in series
                    label.frame.origin.x += ((drawingWidth / CGFloat(labels.count)) / 2) - (label.frame.size.width / 2)
                } else {
                    // Give some space from the vertical line
                    label.frame.origin.x += padding
                }
            }
            self.addSubview(label)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func drawLabelsAndGridOnYAxis() {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setStrokeColor(gridColor.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(0.5)

        var labels: [Float]
        if yLabels == nil {
            labels = [(min.y + max.y) / 2, max.y]
            if yLabelsOnRightSide || min.y != 0 {
                labels.insert(min.y, at: 0)
            }
        } else {
            labels = yLabels!
        }

        let scaled = scaleValuesOnYAxis(labels)
        let padding: CGFloat = 5
        let zero = CGFloat(getZeroValueOnYAxis(zeroLevel: 0))

        scaled.enumerated().forEach { (i, value) in
            let y = CGFloat(value)

            // Add horizontal grid for each label, but not over axes
            if y != drawingHeight + topInset && y != zero {
                context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: y))
                context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: y))
                if labels[i] != 0 {
                    // Horizontal grid for 0 is not dashed
                    context.setLineDash(phase: CGFloat(0), lengths: [CGFloat(5)])
                } else {
                    context.setLineDash(phase: CGFloat(0), lengths: [])
                }
                context.strokePath()
            }

            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: padding, y: y, width: 0, height: 0))
            label.font = labelFont
            label.text = yLabelsFormatter(i, labels[i])
            label.textColor = labelColor
            label.sizeToFit()

            if yLabelsOnRightSide {
                label.frame.origin.x = drawingWidth
                label.frame.origin.x -= label.frame.width + padding
            }

            // Labels should be placed above the horizontal grid
            label.frame.origin.y -= label.frame.height

            self.addSubview(label)
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    fileprivate func drawHighlightLineFromLeftPosition(_ left: CGFloat) {
        if let shapeLayer = highlightShapeLayer {
            // Use line already created
            let path = CGMutablePath()

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: drawingHeight + topInset))
            shapeLayer.path = path
        } else {
            // Create the line
            let path = CGMutablePath()

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: CGFloat(0)))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: drawingHeight + topInset))
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
            shapeLayer.path = path
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = highlightLineColor.cgColor
            shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = highlightLineWidth

            highlightShapeLayer = shapeLayer
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            layerStore.append(shapeLayer)
        }
    }

    func handleTouchEvents(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, event: UIEvent!) {
        let point = touches.first!
        let left = point.location(in: self).x
        let x = valueFromPointAtX(left)

        if left < 0 || left > (drawingWidth as CGFloat) {
            // Remove highlight line at the end of the touch event
            if let shapeLayer = highlightShapeLayer {
                shapeLayer.path = nil
            }
            delegate?.didFinishTouchingChart(self)
            return
        }

        drawHighlightLineFromLeftPosition(left)

        if delegate == nil {
            return
        }

        var indexes: [Int?] = []

        for series in self.series {
            var index: Int? = nil
            let xValues = series.data.map({ (point: ChartPoint) -> Float in
                return point.x })
            let closest = Chart.findClosestInValues(xValues, forValue: x)
            if closest.lowestIndex != nil && closest.highestIndex != nil {
                // Consider valid only values on the right
                index = closest.lowestIndex
            }
            indexes.append(index)
        }

        delegate!.didTouchChart(self, indexes: indexes, x: x, left: left)
    }

    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        handleTouchEvents(touches, event: event)

        leftRangePoint = touches.first!
        leftRangeLocation = leftRangePoint.location(in: self).x
    }

    override open func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        handleTouchEvents(touches, event: event)
        delegate?.didEndTouchingChart(self)

        handleRangeTouchesEnded(touches, event: event)
    }

    func handleRangeTouchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, event: UIEvent!) {
        rightRangePoint = touches.first!
        rightRangeLocation = rightRangePoint.location(in: self).x

        // Make sure left is actually to the left
        if rightRangeLocation < leftRangeLocation {
            let rangePoint = leftRangePoint
            let rangeLocation = leftRangeLocation
            leftRangePoint = rightRangePoint
            leftRangeLocation = rightRangeLocation
            rightRangePoint = rangePoint
            rightRangeLocation = rangeLocation
        }

        // Highlight the range
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let width = rightRangeLocation - leftRangeLocation
        layer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: leftRangeLocation, y: topInset, width: width, height: drawingHeight)).cgPath

        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.opacity = 0.3
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

    override open func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        handleTouchEvents(touches, event: event)
    }

    fileprivate func valueFromPointAtX(_ x: CGFloat) -> Float {
        let value = ((max.x-min.x) / Float(drawingWidth)) * Float(x) + min.x
        return value
    }

    fileprivate func valueFromPointAtY(_ y: CGFloat) -> Float {
        let value = ((max.y - min.y) / Float(drawingHeight)) * Float(y) + min.y
        return -value
    }

    fileprivate class func findClosestInValues(_ values: [Float],
        forValue value: Float
) -> (
            lowestValue: Float?,
            highestValue: Float?,
            lowestIndex: Int?,
            highestIndex: Int?
        ) {
        var lowestValue: Float?, highestValue: Float?, lowestIndex: Int?, highestIndex: Int?

        values.enumerated().forEach { (i, currentValue) in

            if currentValue <= value && (lowestValue == nil || lowestValue! < currentValue) {
                lowestValue = currentValue
                lowestIndex = i
            }
            if currentValue >= value && (highestValue == nil || highestValue! > currentValue) {
                highestValue = currentValue
                highestIndex = i
            }
        }
        return (
            lowestValue: lowestValue,
            highestValue: highestValue,
            lowestIndex: lowestIndex,
            highestIndex: highestIndex
        )
    }

    fileprivate class func segmentLine(_ line: ChartLineSegment, zeroLevel: Float) -> [ChartLineSegment] {
        var segments: [ChartLineSegment] = []
        var segment: ChartLineSegment = []

        line.enumerated().forEach { (i, point) in
            segment.append(point)
            if i < line.count - 1 {
                let nextPoint = line[i+1]
                if point.y >= zeroLevel && nextPoint.y < zeroLevel || point.y < zeroLevel && nextPoint.y >= zeroLevel {
                    // The segment intersects zeroLevel, close the segment with the intersection point
                    let closingPoint = Chart.intersectionWithLevel(point, and: nextPoint, level: zeroLevel)
                    segment.append(closingPoint)
                    segments.append(segment)
                    // Start a new segment
                    segment = [closingPoint]
                }
            } else {
                // End of the line
                segments.append(segment)
            }
        }
        return segments
    }

    fileprivate class func intersectionWithLevel(_ p1: ChartPoint, and p2: ChartPoint, level: Float) -> ChartPoint {
        let dy1 = level - p1.y
        let dy2 = level - p2.y
        return (x: (p2.x * dy1 - p1.x * dy2) / (dy1 - dy2), y: level)
    }
}
```